# how to register / unregister service dynamically

Tags: servicestack

I know you can register a service at runtime by calling the RegisterService method in the appHost extension methods in AppHostExtensions.cs.  Works great.  Is there a way to unRegister a service at run time or clear all services out and re-register them ?

I need this as I want to have a plugin type structure where a dll can be dropped in a folder and servicestack registers all the services at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

No. [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) doesn't support unwiring and un-registering individual services at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a simple brute force approach which works for me.  Would prefer to load and unload individual services but this approach will do.

I added a method to my AppHost file

```
public static void Clear()
{
    Instance = null;
}
```

Then in my mvc controller method where I want to reload servicestack I call

```
AppHost.Instance.Dispose();
AppHost.Clear();
new AppHost().Init();
```

This will reload everything and reinitialise the services which can pick up the new plug in service dll's